# Python: How to create a concurrent-safe reentrant context manager which is different in every context

Tags: python, concurrency, contextmanager, reentrancy

I want to have an object `conManager` that is a [reentrant context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reentrant-context-managers) instance such that whenever I enter and exit its context it will print a number, but the number must be one higher than the number of the previus context (starting at 0).

Example:

```
with conManager:
    print("Afirst")
    with conManager:
        print("Asecond")
        with conManager:
            print("third")
        print("Bsecond")
    print("Bfirst")
```

Output expected:

```
0
Afirst
1
Asecond
2
third
2
Bsecond
1
Bfirst
0
```

The only solution I have so far is a class with a stack in it, but that's not concurrent-safe. Are there any concurrent-safe solutions?

EDIT: as Sraw pointed out, I said thread safe when I meant concurrent-safe, changed the question accordingly.

Comment: why not just a value? You just need to increase and decrease it.

Comment: @Sraw 1. The real example of what i need is more complicated (hence it requires a stack) 2. Ints aren't thread safe either.

Comment: Actually, as there is a GIL in python, `int` and most of basic objects are thread safe including `list`'s `append` and `pop` methods.

Comment: PS: confirmed on linux's cython, not sure about windows.

Comment: @Sraw yes but if I enter two "contexts" of the int before i exit another one asyncronusly (i.e. increment and decrement asyncronously), bugs will happen.

Comment: If you really need to use stack, you can use `list` with its `append` and `pop` methods to simulate a stack. Don't worry, they are thread safe. ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But if a `conManager` exists a context in async, it might pop a value left by another coroutine, making it unsafe, since there's no guarantee that the first context left is the last entered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161177/discussion-between-bentheiii-and-sraw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is overriding `conManager`'s _*call*_ so that **it** returns a context manager, but I'd rather have a cleaner, no-call usage.

EDIT: since someone else showed interest I guess I guess I should post a solution I found

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
from random import randrange
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

context_stack = ContextVar('context_stack')

class ReCm:
    def __init__(self):
        if not context_stack.get(None):
            context_stack.set(WeakKeyDictionary())
        context_stack.get()[self] = []
    def __enter__(self):
        v = randrange(10)
        context_stack.get()[self].append(v)
        print(f'entered {v}')
        return v
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        v = context_stack.get()[self].pop()
        print(f'exited {v}')
```

Comment: what is `__opcall__`?

Comment: Never came up with a better solution for this? That's too bad